# Trying to .slice data in the model before it is saved to the db but it isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, friendly-id

I'm trying to have the slug length be less than 20 if the `key_type` is `4`.

In the model I have

```
validate :text_slug_length

def text_slug_length
 if key_type == 4
   slug.slice(0, 19)
 end

end
```

But this doesn't throw any errors but also doesnt work. Not sure why...

The slug isnt used for values that have a `key_type` of `4`. Data with the `key_type` of `4` can be long slabs of text so it causes length errors when its trying to save a really long slug. I could somehow not save a slug of the `key_type` `4` but this way will also stop the errors from long slugs being generated and I figured `.slice` would be easier.

Can someone help on why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't assign the sliced value.

```
validate :text_slug_length

def text_slug_length
  if key_type == 4
    self.slug = slug.slice(0, 19)
  end
end
```

You might want to check for non-nil value of `slug` first.

Now this does not look like a validation (it does not mark attributes as faulty, it corrects them) but modifies the user input. D'd suggest you use `before_validation` instead (and maybe add a real validation, though this is not necessary because you make sure slug length is not exceeded).

```
before_validation :slice_slug
validates :slug, length: {maximum: 20}, if: :validate_slug_length?

def slice_slug
  self.slug = slug.slice(0, 19) if slug.present? && validate_slug_length?
end

def validate_slug_length?
  key_type == 4
end
```

Comment: How about: `slug.try(:slice!, 0, 19)`? It'll handle `nil` values for `slug`.

Comment: If you use ```try``` then better go for the bang version ```try!```. Personally I don't like try that much but it does the same thing as my ```if```

Comment: Agreed. There is another "syntactic" variation: `slug && slug.slice!(0, 19) && ...`.

Comment: Went with the second option but it doesn't slice the slug. Just gives the validation error

Answer (score 0):

Validations generally add errors to the model if the data is bad. It seems like that's not what you're going for; you just want to truncate the slug if the model's `key_type == 4`, right?  How about just:

```
before_validation :truncate_slug

def truncate_slug
  self.slug = slug.try!(:slice, 0, 19) if key_type == 4
end
```